# TARGET ALWAYS MOVING AND I CAN'T CATCH IT

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, target

I am developing a game where the main character constantly moves at a certain speed and collects coins.

When the coins are collected, an animation(DOTween) moves them to a text that displays the total number of fixed coins on the screen

Vector3 targetPosition = Transform target.position
However, since the character and the background are constantly moving forward, the coins end up going behind the target position. How can i solve this problem ?

Although I tried solutions like FixedUpdate-Update, it didn’t work.
Can you help me with this?

Tried so many things but couldn't solve it, i need you guys to help me really!
here is my code below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using DG.Tweening;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CoinCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("UI reference")]
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text coinUIText;
    [SerializeField] GameObject animatedCoinPrefab;
    [SerializeField] Transform target;

    [Space]
    [Header("Available coins : (coins to pool )")]
    [SerializeField] int maxCoins;
    Queue<GameObject> coinsQueue = new Queue<GameObject>();

    [Space]
    [Header("Animation settings ")]
    [SerializeField] [Range(0.5f,0.9f)] float minAnimDuration;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0.9f,2f)] float maxAnimDuration;

    [SerializeField] Ease easeType;

    Vector3 targetPosition;

    private int _c = 0;

    public int Coins
    {
        get{return _c;}
        set{
            _c = value;
            //update UI text whenever "Coins" variable is changeds
            coinUIText.text = Coins.ToString();
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        targetPosition = target.position;
        //prepare pool
        PrepareCoins();
    }

    void PrepareCoins()
    {
        GameObject coin;
        for(int i = 0; i<maxCoins; i++)
        {
            coin = Instantiate(animatedCoinPrefab);
            coin.transform.parent = transform;
            coin.SetActive(false);
            coinsQueue.Enqueue(coin);
        }
        
    }

    void Animate(Vector3 collectedCoinPosition, int amount)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++)
        {
            //check if there's coins in the pool
            if(coinsQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                //extract a coin from the pool
                GameObject coin = coinsQueue.Dequeue();
                coin.SetActive(true);

                //move coin to the collected coin pos
                coin.transform.position = collectedCoinPosition;

                //animate coin to target position
                float duration = Random.Range(minAnimDuration,maxAnimDuration);
                coin.transform.DOMove(targetPosition,duration).SetEase(easeType).OnComplete(()=>
                {
                    //execute whenever coin reach target position
                    coin.SetActive(false);
                    coinsQueue.Enqueue(coin);

                    Coins++;
                });

            }
        }
    }
    public void AddCoins(Vector3 collectedCoinPosition, int amount)
    {
        Animate(collectedCoinPosition,amount);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldn't spawn more and more objects into the Queue within `FixedUpdate`. You rather want to pre-fill your queue **once** and then only add items on demand if needed.

For example in

```
void PrepareCoins(int amount)
{
    for(var i = 0; i<amount; i++)
    {
        var coin = CreateCoin();
        coinsQueue.Enqueue(coin);
    }
}

GameObject CreateCoin()
{
    var coin = Instantiate(animatedCoinPrefab);
    coin.transform.parent = transform;
    coin.SetActive(false);

    return coin;
}

void Animate(Vector3 collectedCoinPosition, int amount)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++)
    {
        GameObject coin;
        if(coinsQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            coin = coinsQueue.Dequeue();
        }
        else
        {
            // Up to you here whether you want to grow one-by-one e.g.
            coin = CreateCoin();

            // or also e.g. spawn some pre-fill into the queue
            PrepareCoins(amount - i);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

And then I don't know DoTween in specific but you could set the coin as child of the moving target and then rather move in local space

```
...

coin.SetActive(true);
coin.transform.position = collectedCoinPosition;
coin.transform.SetParent(target);

float duration = Random.Range(minAnimDuration,maxAnimDuration);
coin.transform.DOLocalMove(Vector3.zero, duration).SetEase(easeType).OnComplete(()=>
{
    coin.SetActive(false);
    coin.transform.SetParent(transform);
    coinsQueue.Enqueue(coin);

    Coins++;
});

...
```

Comment: Thank you for answer bro, so where should i call CreateCoin then? in update;? and coin is already a child  of moving target, target is moving with background(parallax)

Comment: it should probably rather be a child of the player then .. and `CreateCoin` is called by  `PrepareCoins` and `Animate` in my example

Comment: oo yes i missed that part, thank you for advices bro ! but still  the coins end up going behind the target position.:(((

Comment: bro tried to do same code u gave me but it gives error says :" 'CoinCounter.CreateCoin()': not all code paths return a value"   can you help me about it?

Comment: @hakanmes just add `return coin;` ;) I typed that on the phone ^^